# Running Get-childitem command on a remote machine to retrieve directories

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am fairly new at PowerShell. I am trying to retrieve the directory Names & Mode at depth 2 from a list of servers using the `Get-ChildItem` command.

```
$serverList = import-csv -Path C:\Users\J\Desktop\servers.csv 
ForEach ($server in $serverList)
{
    Get-ChildItem -path $_.server -Recurse -depth 2 `
    | where { $_.PsIsContainer -eq $true}  `
    |select name, mode -Unique | export-csv -Path "C:\Users\J\Desktop\output.csv"
}
```

When I run the script, PowerShell retrieves the directories for my local machine instead of the remote servers. Could someone help me modify my script to get the desired result?

This is a screenshot of the server.csv file

[image]

Comment: PowerShell is expecting a local, or UNC path. Also, if you're on PSv3 you can use `-Directory` instead of your `Where-Object` filter.

Comment: To access a remote machine the path has to  start with two backslashes.  It you have admin you need to replace the colon in the path with a dollar sign.  Either \\serv1\c:\ or \\serv1\c$\  Try same with File Explorer to see if it works putting same into the File Explorer URL